# Where can I find a free .Net (C#) library that I can use to scan and OCR documents?

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, document, ocr

I searching for a free .Net (C#) library that iIcan use to scan from a document scanner, and then OCR the document, so I can get the text from it to save in a database.

After some search I can not find anyone working in Visual Studio 2010 and .Net 4. Someone knows any libs that works like this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use WIA library to control the scanning process and [tesseractdotnet](http://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/) for OCR. <s>An updated .NET 4.0 version can be found [here](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-ocr-dotnet)</s>.

Updated link to .NET wrapper [here](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract)

Comment: tesseractdotnet works fine for english. If it contains arabic content it is not working. Is there any thing for that

Comment: I am having reading text "Album" it reads as "A|bum", Character "L" is replaced by "|".

Comment: isnt tesseractdotnet no longre free?

Answer (score 3):

I think this may  be usef for you [Tessnet2 a .NET 2.0 Open Source OCR Library](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/)