# how to convert image file(like scanned copies) to text file in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can i find a free .Net (C#) library that i can use to scan and OCR documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459013/where-can-i-find-a-free-net-c-library-that-i-can-use-to-scan-and-ocr-documen)

I have a requirement of converting  image file into text file in c#.So please suggest me the solution

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of [OCR applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_optical_character_recognition_software), see:

1. [Where can i find a free .Net (C#) library that i can use to scan and OCR documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459013/where-can-i-find-a-free-net-c-library-that-i-can-use-to-scan-and-ocr-documen)
2. http://www.nicomsoft.com/products/ocr/
3. http://www.imagepdf.com/ocrsdk.htm