# C# : Extract data from image using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, image, itext

Hello I m trying to extract data from scanned document or pdf file which contains images whith some data . For PdF file i have succeeded to read data ,but fro images or pdf that contains pictures , i  failed .
I have converted the image file to pdf but there is no result .
This my small code :

```
 public bool ConvertImageToPdf(string ImageIn, string PDFOut)
        {

            try
            {
                iTextSharp.text.Document doc1 = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
                byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(ImageIn);
                iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(b);
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(PDFOut, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    using (Document doc = new Document(image))
                    {
                        using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                        {

                            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("");
                            doc.Open();

                            image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                            writer.DirectContent.AddImage(image);
                            doc.Add(paragraph); // add paragraph to the document  
                            doc.Add(image); //add an image to the created pdf document
                            doc.Close();
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }



        }
```

And for extracting data , i use this code :

```
   for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    outFile.Write(ExtractTextFromPDFBytes(reader.GetPageContent(page)) + " ");
}
```

the ExtractTextFromPDFBytes(byte[] input) is similar on codeProject [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=14170)

Comment: Putting an image into a pdf will give you a PDF with an image in it ... it will not automatically do any OCR on the image to extract text

Comment: What @devnull69 says is correct: you need OCR and iText doesn't do OCR.

Comment: You're right @devnull69 , i thought that when i add it it will be treated as pdf file and extract data. is that any exemple of OCR which  i can use it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10459013/231316