# Free imaging library (autocontrast, deskew, binarization...)

Tags: c#, .net, image, filter, imaging

I've found paid components like LeadTools, but the project I'm working is open source, I would like to use free tools.

I need to apply several image correction filters to an image to apply some heuristics to it. .NET Framework lacks this kind of filters, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it has all the filters you're looking for, but [ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org/) is one open source SDK you can check out.

Another option is AForge.Net's framework.  [Take a look at their filter documentation](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/).

Comment: Also found this via google search: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/

Comment: I'm mostly interested in image corrections that improve OCR like auto-contrast, auto-binarization, noise removal...

Comment: @SuperJMN: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459013/where-can-i-find-a-free-net-c-library-that-i-can-use-to-scan-and-ocr-documen

Comment: Then take a look at AForge.net's image library, which @Neolisk mentioned.  I'll toss a link in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](https://magick.codeplex.com/) is usually the goto for this sort of thing.

> ImageMagick is a free and open-source software suite for displaying, converting, and editing raster image and vector image files. It can read and write over 200 image file formats. ImageMagick is licensed under the Apache 2.0 license. *(from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick))*